# When I embed video to facebook using the following OG Metadata, I am seeing that facebook is embedding title and domain on the image how to avoid it?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, metadata, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

When I embed video to facebook using the following metadata I am able to embed video succesfully but I don't want facebook to add the text on top of image after embed. How can I do it?

```
<meta property="og:type" content="movie"/>
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
<meta property="og:video" content="http://player.theplatform.com/p/yHjoOC/onsite_dev/swf/select/nEdMK4_islkz&autoPlay=true" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="265" /> 
<meta property="og:video:width" content="470" /> 
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://player.theplatform.com/p/yHjoOC/onsite_dev/swf/select/nEdMK4_islkz&autoPlay=true" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Christina Aguilera On The Voice"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Christina Aguilera gives insight on her team and competition." />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://mpxstatic-nbcmpx.nbcuni.com/NBCdotCOM/mezzthumb/9d883881039c20870dfeaf068a5be0e7_1c966ee53db728d715881e1cf193ebc2.jpg"/>
```

Please help me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its facebook default behavior so we cannot change it